# Creating bins in presto sql - programmatically

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I am new to Presto SQL syntax and and wondering if a function exists that will bin rows into `n` bins in a certain range.

For example, I have a a table with 1m different integers that range from 1 - 100.   What can I do to create 20 bins between 1 and 100 (a bin for 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 ... etc. ) without using 20 separate `CASE WHEN` statements ? Are there any standard SQL functions that do will perform the binning function?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the standard SQL function [`width_bucket`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/math.html#width_bucket). For example:

```sql
WITH data(value) AS (
    SELECT rand(100)+1 FROM UNNEST(sequence(1,10000))
) 
SELECT value, width_bucket(value, 1, 101, 20) bucket
FROM data
```

produces:

```
 value | bucket
-------+--------
   100 |     20
    98 |     20
    38 |      8
    42 |      9
    67 |     14
    74 |     15
     6 |      2
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use integer division:

```
select (intcol - 1) / 5 as bin
```

Presto does integer division, so you shouldn't have to worry about the remainder.